# Duda con while dentro de un do-while en JS

Tags: javascript, while

Tengo un ejercicio que consiste en mostrar todos los múltiplos de 5, menores que 200.
Con un bucle for, y un while con un if aninado no tengo problemas. Pero me pide que use un while y un do while, con lo cual he hecho esto:

```
let multiplo = 5;

do{

    while(multiplo%5==0){
    document.write("<p>"+multiplo+"</p>");

  }
    multiplo++;

}while(multiplo <= 200);
```

Algún ser de luz que me saque de la oscuridad? :/

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual seria el problema?

Comment: Ese while anidado dentro del bucle do no tiene sentido, piensa en cómo lo has hecho en los otros casos

Comment: Según mi lógica, tiene el mismo sentido que hacerlo con un while y un if, verificando que el número sea menor que 200 en el primero y que el resto sea 0 en el segundo. Nunca he anidado while y do while tampoco. No lo veo útil. Pero como es lo que se me pide en una pregunta, intento saber si es posible.

Answer (score 3):

Al final he llegado a la solución. Vengo de java y estaba acostumbrado a usar el modo debug. En js me resulta mas complicado a la hora de ver esta clase de errores. Lo quería hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
let multiplo = 5;


    do{
    
        while(multiplo%5==0){
        document.write("<p>"+multiplo+"</p>");
        multiplo++;
    
      }
    
      multiplo++;
    
    
    }while(multiplo <= 200);
```

Gracias por los comentarios.

Comment: Jmm ahí me jodiste, no se me ocurre nada pero no intentare. Te pidieron que lo hicieras así?, sin condicionarlo con un `if`

Comment: Editado mi comentario, que después de un día y medio me vino la luz. Si, me lo pedían de esa manera estricta.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que entendí fue esto, por medio de ciclos ir evaluando si tal numero es múltiplo de 5 hasta que llegue a 200.
Esto fue lo que pude hacer, hazme saber si es lo que estabas buscando

```
let numero = 0
do {

  while (numero <= 200) {

    if (numero % 5 == 0 ) {
        console.log(`${numero} es múltiplo de 5.`)
    }
    numero++
  }
  
} while (numero >= 200);
```

Como puedes ver el `Do While` es el que se va a encargar de que se realice el ciclo siempre y cuando numero sea menor que 200 mientras que el `While` se va a repetir las veces necesarias en este caso 200 y dentro un `if` que va a evaluar si el numero es **múltiplo de 5**.

Saludos.

Comment: Ahí no mas cambias el `console.log` por la etiqueta

Comment: Es correcto lo que has entendido. Aunque no comprendo porque introduces el do-while, cuando en este caso, con la estructura while-if seríe suficiente para mostrar todos los multiplos de 5 hasta 200.

Comment: También se puede hacer así solo que no lo hice y como habías pedido `do-while` y `while` me fui directo a eso, ahí la anexo a la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que el problema es irreal, así que no interesa que se la forma logica, si no que cumpla.

Yo separé los número del 1 al 200 como si fuera una matriz de 10x20, y la recorrí como tal

```js
let multiplo1 = 0;
let multiplo2 = 0;
do{

    while(multiplo2<10){
      let multi = multiplo1 * 10 + multiplo2 + 1;
      if(multi % 5 == 0){
         document.write("<p>"+ multi +"</p>");
      }
      
      multiplo2++;
    }
    multiplo2=0;
    multiplo1++;

}while(multiplo1 < 20);
```